# How to use multiple blocks from different files?

Tags: node.js, templates, express, pug

I have a `layout.jade` that looks like this:

```
html
  body
    block content
    block footer
```

My `content.jade` looks like that:

```
extends layout

block content
    #Content Welcome
```

My `footer.jade` looks like that:

```
extends layout

block footer
    #Footer Impressum
```

Now, when I run my `app` like that:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('layout');
});
```

I do not see neither the content nor the footer.

When I run:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('content');
});
```

Then I see the content.

When I run:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('footer');
});
```

Then I see the footer.

How can I see both, content and footer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

`layout.jade`

```
html
  body
    block content
    include footer
```

`pagename.jade`

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 My Content
```

`footer.jade`

```
p.footer Here is my footer
```

Then run `res.render('pagename');`.

Unless you want to have specific stuff in your footer per page, there's no point in making it a block.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Could I also replace `block content` with `include #{page}`. And run `res.render('layout', { page: 'pagename' });`?

Comment: You could, but I would argue that it's semantically more correct to `render` the page associated with your route (unless you have some other reason for doing things differently, of course). \[Edit\] At least, I _think_ you can. :)

Comment: Fair enough :) I will go wih your suggestion. Thanks!